# Несколько типов аргумента метода

Tags: php

Написал метод для класса:

```
public function setOption(string $field, $value) : self {
    $this->options[$field] = $value;
    return $this;
}
```

Теперь требуется доработать этот метод, чтобы он мог принимать в аргументе `$field` массив, и в зависимости от типа данных производит другие действия.

Есть ли в php механизм перезагрузки методов, например как в с++ ?

Я где-то видел, что можно писать так: `string|array $field` но помню, что по этому поводу были отрицательные отзывы из-за каких-то ошибок.

Не подскажите как решить проблему? какие есть варианты и к каким ошибкам могут приводить перечисление нескольких типов? или это нормальная практика?

Строгую типизацию требуется поддержать. Решение желательно не костыльное (на подобие проверок на тип данных и выбрасыванием исключений).

Comment: _как решить проблему?_ Никак. php - нетипизированный язык в отличие от с++. так что перегрузка функций по типу аргументов здесь в принципе невозможна.

Comment: @hindmost, вы не правы. В 7 версии появилась возможность типизации аргументов и возвращаемых типов. В 7.4 появится типизация полей классов